# Websites that contain useful and reliable scripts for sql server?

Tags: sql-server

Are there any useful and reliable, keyword being reliable here that contain sql server scripts, especially for viewing the statistical usage of the database.  I know there are a lot of sql server sites that have scripts, but you never know if they are reliable scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the folks who put together this site and they are all very smart capable people, some of who work on extremely large databases.

http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Category:Microsoft_SQL_Server_Admin

Answer (score 0):

**always read the code in all scripts you download**  If you run it, you are responsible for what happens.  Try to understand what it is doing by looking at the code, if you don't understand something, ask on SO.  If you are not sure about something, don't run it.

[Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/index.html) has some good stuff.